# PHP data taken from one MySQL table, displayed to user and than new data plus this data being written to new table

Tags: php, mysql, multiple-tables

OK that probably sounded a bit confusing but what I have is a table that spits out courses locations and dates depending on what the user chooses.  I than want the user to go through the fields and than on the 3rd submit button I have the course information displayed to them. I'm asking how in php i can take the echo from the first query and use that to upload it to the other table.  Would I just be using MySQL Links?

Comment: darn it i meant table not database in the title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple pages, you can use `$_SESSION` variables to store the data for when you're ready for it.

If you have one page, with multiple forms, you can use `<input type='hidden' />` fields to hold the data until you're ready for it (it will be stored in `$_POST` each time you submit the form).

Then, when you're ready, pull the info out of the `$_SESSION` or `$_POST` data and run your query.

For the $_POST solution:

```
<form action='' method='post' >
  <input type='hidden' name='data1' 
    value="<? if(isset($_POST['data1'])) { echo $_POST['data1']; } ?>"
  <input type='hidden' name='data2' 
    value="<? if(isset($_POST['data2'])) { echo $_POST['data2']; } ?>"
  <input type='hidden' name='data3' 
    value="<? if(isset($_POST['data3'])) { echo $_POST['data3']; } ?>"
</form>

<?
if(isset($_POST['data1'] && isset($_POST['data2'] && isset($_POST['data3']) {
  //Run your query, echo results
}
?>
```